# iOS 8 Application crashes when opening PDF file in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, ios8

I have a Javascript application that runs into a UIWebView on iOS. This application sends commands to the native application (Objective-C) to control its behavior like changing the color of the status bar, or open another UIWebView to load an external web page or file.

Since the release of iOS 8, I’m receiving a huge quantity of crash reports that are all generated from the same error. I was able to reproduce the crash with an iPhone 5S on iOS 8.

When I open and close several external UIWebView with a link to a PDF file, the application crashes after 4-5 times. This is the crashing thread in the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x370d8ba8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x371541fa _pthread_mutex_lock + 274
2   WebCore                       0x346407cc _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 40
3   WebCore                        0x34640fe8 WebThreadLock + 76
4   UIKit                         0x2d4e1be0 -[UIWebBrowserView _webTouchEventsRecognized:] + 520
5   UIKit                         0x2d36b556 -[UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer _processTouches:withEvent:type:] + 294
6   UIKit                         0x2d36b6c6 -[UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 146
7   UIKit                          0x2d013538 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 408
8   UIKit                         0x2d012f88 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 520
9   UIKit                         0x2cfe9a04 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
10  UIKit                         0x2d25bade _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13842
11  UIKit                         0x2cfe849c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1300
12  CoreFoundation                0x299b257c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                0x299b198a __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 214
14  CoreFoundation                0x299afff0 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
15  CoreFoundation                0x298fe60c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
16  CoreFoundation                0x298fe41e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
17  GraphicsServices              0x30e580a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
18  UIKit                         0x2d048480 UIApplicationMain + 1436
19  MyApp                          0x000c5472 main (main.m:16)
20  libdyld.dylib                  0x37012aac start + 0
```

This is the part of the code where the new web view is called when the file has finished downloading. At the end, the native application calls a Javascript method to tell my JS app that the file has been downloaded.

Even if I break in this code, I have no clue where it crashed.

```
NSLog(@"Download completed");
docPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
if (![docPath isEqualToString:docPath]) {
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:docPath error:&error];
}
bool saved =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docPath contents:fileData attributes:nil];
if(saved){
      WebViewController *wController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
      wController.isExternalWebView=true;
      wController.showToolbar=FALSE;
      wController.showNavigationBar=TRUE;
      wController.showActionInNavigationBar=TRUE;
      wController.actions= @[@"Print",@"OpenIn"];
      wController.initialURLRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:docPath]];
      wController.actionSheetTitle=[inArguments objectForKey:@"TextTitlePopup"];
      wController.title=[inArguments objectForKey:@"TextTitle"];
      [weakSelf.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                                       initWithTitle: [inArguments objectForKey:@"TextBackBtn"]
                                                                       style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                       target: nil action: nil]];

      [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:wController animated:YES];
}else{
      NSLog(@"COULD NOT SAVE FILE");
}

NSLog(@"START!");
[self.downloadOperation  start];

NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"App.DocumentCallBack();"];
[mWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

The code of my Javascript and Objective-C has not changed since iOS 8 release. With iOS 7, this crash was happening only a few times in a month. Now, it’s happening more than 100 times a day.

Does anyone know what can cause this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using the inAppBrowser plugin to display it?

Comment: No, my application does not use Cordova, I am using the native UIWebView.